# Why won't my edit and delete links work on my index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of post titles sorted under an alphabetical letter but my edit links and delete links aren't working on my index page. They do work when i add them to the show page. I thought i had this working before but get the error "undefined local variable posts" I have tried this.

```
edit_post_path(posts)
edit_post_path(@post)
edit_post_path(@posts)
```

**posts controller**

```
def index
      @posts = current_user.posts.all.group_by {|post| ('a'..'z').include?(post.title.downcase[0]) ? post.title.downcase[0] : '#' }
end

def edit
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
end


def update
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to action: "index"
      flash[:success] = "Post Updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
end


def destroy
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to action: "index"
    flash[:success] = "Post Deleted"
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.keys.sort.each do |key| %>  

  <div class= "posts-letter"><%= key.upcase %></div>

  <% @posts[key].each do |t| %>  
      <div class="post">  

          <div class="post-title"><%= t.title %></div>

          <div class="action-buttons"> 

              <%= link_to edit_post_path(post), class: "edit-button" do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              <% end %>

              <%= link_to  post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class: "delete-button" do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
              <% end %>

          </div>

      </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `t` is your post object inside the `each`.  So you would pass that to `edit_post_path`.  Or you could name it `post` instead of `t`.

```
  <% @posts[key].each do |post| %>  
      <div class="post">  

          <div class="post-title"><%= post.title %></div>

          <div class="action-buttons"> 

              <%= link_to edit_post_path(post), class: "edit-button" do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              <% end %>

              <%= link_to post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, class: "delete-button" do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
              <% end %>

          </div>

      </div>
  <% end %>
```